# Postgres row count

Tags: postgresql, count, postgresql-8.4

I have a table with a row count of 985 records. But it is really slow to query this table.

```
# select count(*) from movie;
 count 
-------
   985
```

Then I perform query using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` The row count over here is 1636712, which is very much different from 985. Why is this happen and how to fix this?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM movie;
QUERY PLAN                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=194963.62..194963.63 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=21051.607..21051.607 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on movie  (cost=0.00..190852.29 rows=1644529 width=0) (actual time=2813.737..21051.094 rows=985 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 21053.506 ms
```

`\d movie`

```
Indexes:
    "movie_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (movie_id)
    "index_movie_internal_id" btree (movie_internal_id)
    "movie_release_date_index" btree (movie_release_date DESC NULLS LAST, movie_internal_title)
    "movie_release_date_title_index" btree (movie_release_date, movie_internal_title)


# VACUUM FULL ANALYZE movie; EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM movie;
    VACUUM
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=194963.62..194963.63 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=21051.607..21051.607 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on movie  (cost=0.00..190852.29 rows=1644529 width=0) (actual time=2813.737..21051.094 rows=985 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 21053.506 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8.4 is very old. It was EOL in 2014. 9.2 came out in 2012 and it solves all these problems. You need to upgrade to a modern version of PostgreSQL that supports index-only scans.